# Replacements only in the first line with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

There is a transform of multiline string.

```
!a! b!
```

should become

```
.a. b.
```

And

```
!a! b!
c!
!d!
```

should become

```
.a. b.
c!
!d!
```

I approached it with a lookbehind:

```
str(/(?<!\n)([^\n!]*)!+/g, '$1.')
```

It didn't work as intended:

```
.a. b.
c.
!d.
```

Splitting a string and transforming the first line seems straightforward. But is there a reliable way to do replacements only in the first line of multiline string with a regex only?

Also would appreciate an explanation what exactly goes wrong with my approach so it fails.

The question is not limited to JS regex flavour but I'm interested in this one in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps using 2 capturing groups `!([^\s!]+)!([^\S\r\n]+[^\s!])!` https://regex101.com/r/QtwImV/1 and replace with `.$1.$2.`

Comment: You can also use SKIP FAIL for example `^!?[^\r\n!]*!$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|!` https://regex101.com/r/eAwZHD/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot, both suggestions look good, consider posting them as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the pattern you tried:

- `(?<!\n)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not a newline or !
- `([^\n!]*)` Capture group 1, match 0+ times any char except a newline or !
- `!+` Match 1+ times ! (What you want to remove)

The pattern will match too much, as it will match all the individual parts. There is for example no rule that says match this pattern 2 times, so you will replace with group 1 for every time that pattern has a match.

Note that the quantifier in this part is 0+ times `([^\n!]*)` it will also match a single ! except when preceded by a newline.

---

If you can make use of SKIP FAIL, you can first match what you want to avoid, which in this case is a line that optionally starts with an exclamation mark and ends with an exclamation mark with none in between.

After that match all the other exclamation marks and replace them with a dot.

```
^!?[^\r\n!]*!$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|!
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAwZHD/1)

---

Another option could be using 2 capturing groups.

The first group will match between the first set of exclamation marks, and the second group will match the whitespaces after followed by a char other than !.

Then match the ! at the end so it is not in the replacement

```
 !([^\s!]+)!([^\S\r\n]+[^\s!])!
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QtwImV/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups with the dots

```
.$1.$2.
```